Recieve .json data from an API and extract the information for later use
I'm just getting started with programming an Raspberry PI.
I'm having troubble extracting information, I get from an API.

I send a picture to the "Goolge Visions API" to extract the "setname" as well as "cardid"
then I send a API request to the "Scryfall API" to recieve .json data.
from this data I need to extract "color_identity""colors" and "eur".

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Python to resolve this issue.
this is what I came up with after some hours looking in the web.
import requests
import json

setname = "xln"      #this is the ID of the Set*
cardid = "96"        #this is the set specific id of the card*

response_API = requests.get('https://api.scryfall.com/cards/'setname'/'cardid'.json')
data = response_API.text
parse_json = json.loads(data)
card_list = []

for item in json_array:
    card_details = {"color_identity":None, "colors":None, "eur":None}
    card_details['color_identity'] = item ['color_identity']
    card_details['colors'] = item ['colors']
    card_details['eur'] = item ['eur']
    card_list.append(card_details)

print(card_list)



Hi, the url response is not correct: https://api.scryfall.com/cards/xln/96.json, if you can fix that we can help you better.

Thank you for the information.
aparently it should only be:
"https://api.scryfall.com/cards/xln/96"

Your url did not work, so the code is not tested!
You could do something like this, but there are many other option to deal with requests and json data in python.
import json

setname = "xln"      #this is the ID of the Set*
cardid = "96"        #this is the set specific id of the card*

response_API = requests.get(f'https://api.scryfall.com/cards/{setname}/{cardid}.json')
if response_API.status_code == 200:
    data = response_API.json()
    assert isinstance(data, list), "response is not a list"
    card_list = [
        {
            'color_identity': x.get('color_identity'),
            'colors': x.get('colors'),
            'eur': x.get('eur')
        } for x in data
    ]
else:
    print('No correct request was made')
    print(response_API.content.decode())


The request to the API is made like you did (but I prefer  f-strings, but your method may also work.
Check is the response code is 200: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
Read data in a dictionary (python object)
Check if the data is of type list (that is needed since you go over the list to extract all card details).
Use a list comprehension to go over each item in the data list (this is of type list now, because it is checked before). Use the get method since that returns None if the key is not in the element dictionary. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions and https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp

EDIT
So the url is fixed, now one can extract the information.
The error shows us that the response is not a list. This means that the returned json only contain information about one item (I assume that this is a card, but I am unfamiliar with the data).
So when 1 cardid is requested, it returned values for 1 card only like this:
import json
import requests

setname = "xln"      #this is the ID of the Set*
cardid = "96"        #this is the set specific id of the card*

response_API = requests.get(f'https://api.scryfall.com/cards/{setname}/{cardid}')
if response_API.status_code == 200:
    data = response_API.json()
    card = {
        'color_identity': data.get('color_identity'),
        'colors': data.get('colors'),
        'eur': data.get('prices', {}).get('eur')
    } 
else:
    print('No correct request was made')
    print(response_API.content.decode())
print(card)
>>> {'color_identity': ['B'], 'colors': ['B'], 'eur': '0.12'}



the f-string version works perfectly. my mistake was the .json ending
yes I receive a 200 Response code. checked with "print({r.status.code})"
it seems that the received data is not a list. => AssertionError: response is not a list

==> I used this as a reference "https://scryfall.com/docs/api/cards/collector"

I figured out a solution with your help.
switching to a "f-string" for the URL helped a lot as well as having a status code 200 Query.
Here is the code:
import requests
import json
import urllib

cardset = "xln"
cardid = "96"
url = f"https://api.scryfall.com/cards/{cardset}/{cardid}"
r = requests.get(url)
r.status_code
#print({r.status_code})        #for debug purposes
if r.status_code == 200:
    data = r.json()
    coloridentity = data["color_identity"]
    colors = data["colors"]
    price = data["prices"]["eur"]
    #print(coloridentity)      #for debug purposes
    #print(colors)             #for debug purposes
    #print(price)              #for debug purposes
else:
    print('No correct request was made')
    print(response_API.content.decode())

